# How to lower the size of the round animated search button?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a animated search bar on my navigation bar but it is big so would like to know how to reduce the size so it could fit in. This is a little disturbing for me since i am a newbee in web developing field. So thanks in advance.

this is the code i am using:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:700");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 10;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}

.container .search {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: crimson;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.container .search:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .search::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 22px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 22px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.container .search::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.container input {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: crimson;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px crimson;
  padding: 0 80px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 crimson, 0 20px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.container input:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container input:focus {
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: text;
}

.container input:focus~.search {
  right: -250px;
  background: #151515;
  z-index: 6;
}

.container input:focus~.search::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25px;
}

.container input:focus~.search::after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.container input::placeholder {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <div class="search"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: reduce the width/height of .container .search ?

Comment: Also add box-sizing:border-box; for *::before, *::after this way the offscreen behaviour would be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the style of `.container .search` as below

```
.container .search {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: crimson;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: 4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.container .search::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -5px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```